# Delete data or CSV file using SSIS or C#

Tags: c#, ssis

I'm trying to:

1. Delete data from a `CSV` file using `SSIS` or `C#`. If I can't delete data then,
2. At least delete `CSV` file using `SSIS` or `C#`.

I want to know how to do #1 if it is possible.

Comment: To restate desire 1, you'd like to know how to `Delete rows n-m`?

Comment: Instead of asking if it's possible and asking for code, maybe you could show us what you have tried to do for yourself that you are having trouble with.

Comment: @billinkc: you're correct. trying to see how to delete rows in csv file using ssis or C#.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete all the rows in CSV file by using C#... then follow the below code...

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"D:/filename.csv",string.Empty);
```

it delete all the rows and keep the file as empty...

Comment: Oops i think i found the solution myself, there is overwrite option in the flat file connection, so process overwrite everytime i guess. Looks like it's working.

Answer (score 0):

### C#

To remove lines from a flat file, you'll need to read the file and write it out to another file excluding any of the lines you don't want.

Read these two articles, they're short

- [Reading a Text File One Line at a Time](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287535%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)
- [Writing to a Text File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287548%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

There may be more clever ways of zipping to a particular location. If it were a fixed width file, then you could calculate where to go and how much to strip but since it's a CSV, you're humped on that accord.

### SSIS

I'm assuming the desire to remove the lines is a header or trailer as SSIS before SQL Server 2012 didn't play well with those. In that case, you're going to want to establish 2 connection managers. One will read the entire file in a single column. The second will be your well formatted file output. The same work flow will happen here.

In a data flow task, add a `Flat File Source` and configure it to use the 1 column connection manager. Add a `Derived Column component` or a `Script Component` to enable you to determine whether this row is a keeper or not. Add a `Conditional Split` off that and shunt only the good rows to a `Flat File Destination` which uses your strongly typed definition.

Then in your next Data Flow, use a `Flat File Source` connected to the strongly typed definition and bob's your uncle.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.IO;     
string path = @"c:\temp\a.txt";

if (File.Exists(path))
{
   File.Delete(path);
}
```